# Capistrano problem in Amazon Web Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I'm running Rails + Passenger under an Ubuntu AWS's instance. Now I'm trying to deploy with Capistrano, I already did my git repository (and upload it to the server) and my deploy.rb file (with capify .). I already runned `cap deploy:setup` and `cap deploy:check` with success. But now when I try to run `cap deploy` it fail and I get this error http://pastebin.com/uzkerA9F

Comment: Might want to try serverfault.com

Comment: When I try to clone my git repository inside my server , it ask for my passphrase... I think this could be the problem...

@ctcherry thanks, and sorry

Comment: Its all good, I'm glad you are on the path to a solution!

Comment: Well, I found the problem and solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269578/capistrano-asks-for-password-when-deploying-despite-ssh-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem and solution here
[Capistrano asks for password when deploying, despite SSH keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269578/capistrano-asks-for-password-when-deploying-despite-ssh-keys)

So > I add `set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}` to my deploy.rb file

---