# Capistrano asks for SSH password when it should use the SSH key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano, private-key

I have several Rails apps that use Capistrano.

When I sign in to the deployment server in the OSX Terminal.app I'm prompted for the password of my `ida_rsa` ssh key and I can successfully sign into the server with the given user.

Now when deploying to the same server with the same username I'm prompted for the **server password** of that user instead of the password to unlock my `id_rsa` private key.

I tried a number of things:

1. Add `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true` to `deploy.rb`
2. `ssh-copy-id` this worked and I can already SSH to the server in the Terminal, which shows that this method does work.
3. `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

I would prefer to use my SSH key since I can't remember all of my servers passwords and I might want to disable password-SSH-login alltogether in the future too.

I know that my questions looks like an exact duplicate of [Capistrano asks for password when deploying, despite SSH keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269578/capistrano-asks-for-password-when-deploying-despite-ssh-keys) however, since none of the answers, including the approved answer did work for me I'm asking a new question.

## My environment:

```
➜ cat Gemfile.lock | grep capistrano | grep "("
    capistrano (3.17.1)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-puma (0.2.3)
      capistrano (>= 3.0)
    capistrano-rails (1.6.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.1, < 3)
    capistrano-rbenv (2.2.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
  capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1.2)
  capistrano-rails (~> 1.1)
```

I'm using Rails 4.2.11.3

#### Permissions

I also tried to change the permissions of the files within `~/.ssh` like so:

```
chmod u+rw,go-rwx .ssh/id_rsa
chmod u+rw,go-rwx .ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod u+rw,go-rwx .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod u+rw,go-rwx .ssh/known_hosts
```

This did not result in any change regarding the password.

These are my `ssh_options`from my `production.rb`:

```
set :ssh_options, {
    forward_agent: true,
    verbose: :debug,
    auth_methods: %w(publickey password),
    keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa)
}
```

Please note that the following in the terminal works fine:

```
ssh myproject@dev.example.com # id_rsa is used
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-57-generic x86_64)
```

### Log

```
cap production deploy
      rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/2.6.0/open3.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/me in PATH, mode 040777
00:00 git:push_sources
      01 git push origin main:main --force
      01 Everything up-to-date
    ✔ 01 me@localhost 0.528s
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.063747 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3fc260d9f0b4]: establishing connection to dev.example.com:22
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.084268 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[3fc260d9f0b4]: connection established
I, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.084647 #8626]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fc260d9e614]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.084934 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fc260d9e614]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_4.2.0 x86_64-darwin20'
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.125834 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[3fc260d9e614]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3'
I, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.131316 #8626]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fc260da74a8]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.132134 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1156
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.132245 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: sent 1160 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143117 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: read 1080 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143224 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 1076
I, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143262 #8626]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fc260da74a8]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143331 #8626]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fc260da74a8]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143454 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fc260da74a8]: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
* host_key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
* encryption_server: aes128-ctr
* encryption_client: aes128-ctr
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client: 
* language_server: 
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143481 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[3fc260da74a8]: exchanging keys
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143645 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.143870 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.222189 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: read 280 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.223277 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 276
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.235760 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 268
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.236019 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: sent 272 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.254971 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: read 504 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.255263 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 484
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.257890 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.257984 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.258046 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.258392 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fc260ce7e00]: beginning authentication of `myproject'
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.258557 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.258615 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: sent 52 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.335033 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: read 52 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.335202 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.335309 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fc260ce7e00]: trying publickey
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337096 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fc260cf75bc]: connecting to ssh-agent
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337260 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fc260cf75bc]: sending agent request 1 len 47
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337406 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fc260cf75bc]: received agent packet 5 len 1
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337444 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fc260cf75bc]: sending agent request 11 len 0
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337553 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[3fc260cf75bc]: received agent packet 12 len 313
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337775 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[3fc260cf3868]: trying publickey (9f:9e:f5:2a:11:d2:c2:53:fb:17:44:81:b5:65:16:7c)
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.337956 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 348
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.338032 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: sent 372 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.361596 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: read 68 bytes
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.361844 #8626] DEBUG -- socket[3fc260d9ece0]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 44
D, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.361938 #8626] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fc260ce7e00]: allowed methods: publickey,password
E, [2023-03-31T12:31:54.361985 #8626] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3fc260ce7e00]: all authorization methods failed (tried publickey)
#<Thread:0x00007f84c1a7d148@/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as myproject@dev.example.com: Authentication failed for user myproject@dev.example.com (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:254:in `start': Authentication failed for user myproject@dev.example.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in `with_ssh'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in `execute_command'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.17.1/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
        from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.6.10/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.3/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as myproject@dev.example.com: Authentication failed for user myproject@dev.example.com


Caused by:
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user myproject@dev.example.com

Tasks: TOP => deploy:check => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as myproject@dev.example.com: Authentication failed for user myproject@dev.example.com


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


  INFO START 2023-03-31 12:28:44 +0200 cap production deploy

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv

  INFO [952e12b2] Running /usr/bin/env git push origin main:main --force as me@localhost

  INFO [952e12b2] Finished in 0.580 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [6a82481f] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as myproject@dev.example.com

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO START 2023-03-31 12:29:39 +0200 cap production deploy

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv

  INFO [eba965ea] Running /usr/bin/env git push origin main:main --force as me@localhost

  INFO [eba965ea] Finished in 0.604 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [9ec098a4] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as myproject@dev.example.com

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO START 2023-03-31 12:31:53 +0200 cap production deploy

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv

  INFO [b15f7565] Running /usr/bin/env git push origin main:main --force as me@localhost

  INFO [b15f7565] Finished in 0.528 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

  INFO [b3ed8356] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as myproject@dev.example.com
```

Comment: update `net-ssh` gem. it does the actual connecting.

Comment: @Alex: I did run `bundle update net-ssh` but it remained at `Using net-ssh 4.2.0` / "Bundler attempted to update net-ssh but its version stayed the same".

Comment: try adding it to Gemfile and set the version. `gem "net-ssh", ">= 7.0"`. sshkit doesn't have the upper limit on it, but i don't know if you have something that does.

Comment: @Alex: This did in fact fix the issue. You may post an answer and I'll happily award you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why updating `net-ssh` gem works. But I did a bit of debugging:

```
# net-ssh v6.1.0
>> Net::SSH.start("myhost.com", "root", keys: ["/home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa"])
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:268:in `start':
Authentication failed for user root@myhost.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
```

On the server:

```bash
$ tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Apr  3 04:15:42 myhost sshd[2548315]: userauth_pubkey: 
  key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
#          ^              ^
```

---

### Add ssh-rsa to accepted algorithms

*not recommended*

```bash
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config

PubKeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

```bash
sudo service ssh restart
```

Verify:

```rb
>> Net::SSH.start("myhost.com", "root", keys: ["/home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa"]) do |ssh|
     ssh.exec!("hostname")
   end
=> "myhost\n"
```

---

### Update net-ssh

Updating to `net-ssh` version `7` also fixes the issue. Not sure which config changed, but I'm thinking maybe this:

*https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/commit/a45f54fe1de434605af0b7195dd9a91bccd2cec5*

---

**update**

I've checked that ^ commit, that's the one. I've also noticed this [commit](https://github.com/mrsked/mrsk/commit/d8c61004e4799902bbf58d8dd3287970a36b3b6a) on `mrsk` that sums it up:

> **Require net-ssh ~> 7.0 for SHA-2 support**
> Versions of net-ssh before 7.0 do not support the SHA-2 algorithm and result in mrsk not being able to connect to hosts using keys generated with it. net-ssh is also a dependency of sshkit, however, sshkit has a version requirement of >= 2.8.0 for net-ssh, so is not effective at ensuring mrsk has the version it needs to be the most compatible.

Comment: Brilliant and thanks for doing the extra research!

Comment: Within a Rails project `bundle update sshkit` (dependency of `capistrano`) did the trick for me. It updated `net-ssh` from `6.1.0` to `7.2.0`. Solving the issue as a result.

Answer (score -1):

When you deploy, you use a command like: `cap my_server deploy`, and there should be an ssh configuration for "my_server" in ~/.ssh/config.

You should be able to do `ssh my_server` from the command line without having to type the server p/w, because its ssh configuration should be appropriately  configured for this. Here is a typical ssh configuration in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host my_server
  HostName <ip address of server>
  Port 22
  user <user who logs in to server>
  ForwardAgent yes
  PubkeyAuthentication yes
  IdentityFile /absolute/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa
```